# SQL sorting such that rows are sorted only where another column value is equal

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query problem. So here is a table which is a result of a large query.

`+---------+-------------+------------+
| page_id | TotalDegree | matchCount |
+---------+-------------+------------+
|     116 |      7.0000 |          4 |
|     142 |      3.0000 |          4 |
|     109 |      4.0000 |          2 |
|     119 |      4.0000 |          2 |
|     108 |      2.0000 |          2 |
|     132 |      4.0000 |          1 |
|     133 |      9.0000 |          1 |
|     146 |      9.0000 |          1 |
|     114 |      4.0000 |          1 |
|     125 |      9.0000 |          1 |
|     113 |      1.0000 |          1 |
|     127 |      9.0000 |          1 |
|     120 |      4.0000 |          1 |
|     129 |      9.0000 |          1 |
|     121 |      9.0000 |          1 |
+---------+-------------+------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Now I want to sort a table on the basis of 'TotalDegree' in ascending order such that sorting should be done internally where the 'matchCount' column value is same.
Example: The first two rows has 'matchCount' value 4 so sorting should be done in between these two rows on the basis of 'TotalDegree' in ascending order.
Similarly, all the rows with 'matchCount' equals to 1 should be sorted amongst themselves.
So the sorted table should look like as below.

`+---------+-------------+------------+
| page_id | TotalDegree | matchCount |
+---------+-------------+------------+
|     142 |      3.0000 |          4 |
|     116 |      7.0000 |          4 |
|     108 |      2.0000 |          2 |
|     109 |      4.0000 |          2 |
|     119 |      4.0000 |          2 |
|     113 |      1.0000 |          1 |
|     132 |      4.0000 |          1 |
|     114 |      4.0000 |          1 |
|     120 |      4.0000 |          1 |
|     133 |      9.0000 |          1 |
|     146 |      9.0000 |          1 |
|     125 |      9.0000 |          1 |
|     127 |      9.0000 |          1 |
|     129 |      9.0000 |          1 |
|     121 |      9.0000 |          1 |
+---------+-------------+------------+`

How can such a query can be designed ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sort on MatchCount first (in descending order),
then on TotalDegree (in ascending order).

```
select * from TableName  
order by MatchCount desc, TotalDegree asc;
```

Comment: Feeling embarrassed for my low knowledge in SQL and not having this concept clear. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [order by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) clause

```
select * from fooTable order by foo1 desc, foo2 asc
```

in your case:

```
select  page_id ,TotalDegree , matchCount  from fooFable order by matchCount  desc, TotalDegree asc
```